# Android developments of packet routing and control

Tags: android, linux, routes

I try to find a method for android devices to be routers as my goal is to control packets and even implement different routing algorithm. I don't know how does Android OS surport. As I knew, Android OS includes Wifi hotspot features. But the features are limited, there are no advance settings like routing table, firewall, ARP, NAT... 
I also find some APP like "[Droidwall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&hl=zh_TW)" which can act as firewall for each application with root permission. It means there are some API for developer. Where can I find some resources(document or sample code) about the related developments? Which features could Android surport?

Comment: I don't think there are APIs, this app probably interacts directly with the linux kernel. You can use tools like apktool or dex2jar to decompile the app and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used adb shell to make some Linux command. "DroidWall" can be implemented by using "iptables" command. I try to write an app where I can make some shell command when some events occurred . But I'm using shell command to control now.